# SQL ORACLE SELECT WILDCARD Invalid Number

Tags: sql, oracle

I encountered a weird error in Oracle SQL. It prompts me an error that says 'Invalid Number' even though the field/column is not Number.

Y'all have any idea what's going on?

Here's the SQL.

```
Select * from Products where Prod_nm like '%A%';
```

I use this same SQL statement on other Tables and got no errors.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `Prod_nm` must be a number column, no other explenation for this error.

Comment: "I use this same SQL statement on other Tables and got no errors.". You can't use the same `SQL` queries on all tables and expect the same results, unless the tables are identical. Can you provide your schema?

Comment: Unfortunately, OP's error comes from a part of the query (a join) that wasn't specified. The actual details are given in comments on the answer. I'm voting to close this question as 'can't reproduce'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can [read here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-01722):

> An ORA-01722 ("invalid number") error occurs when an attempt is made to convert a character string into a number, and the string cannot be converted into a valid number... When doing a SELECT... **Check for a numeric column being compared to a character column**...

The conclusion is that your table column `Prod_nm` **must be a numeric column**, otherwise this error message would have never appeard. Double check your database structure.

---

**EDIT**

As you mentioned in the comments, the query you are using:

```
Select * from Products 
Inner join Review 
ON Products.prod_id = Review.prod_id 
where Products.prod_nm like '%A%'
```

Is joining (using `ON`) a **numeric** column (`Review.prod_id`) with a **varchar** column (`Products.prod_id`), and that is where the error comes from.

Comment: Hi @koby, Prod_nm is Varchar2.

Comment: @LexDacs That's not possible, are you 100% sure?

Comment: Yes,sir it is. Actually, The original query is 

`Select * from Products Inner join Review ON Products.prod_id = Review.prod_id where Products.prod_nm like '%A%'`

Comment: Either `Review.prod_id` or `Products.prod_id` is numeric

Comment: `Review.review_id` is numeric though. I'm sorry it should not be `Review.prod_id` but `review_id`

Comment: @LexDacs That's the prblem then. You cannot compare a numeric with a varchar

Comment: @LexDacs That's not possible. You cannot perform this kind of `on`